# JOIN clause for multi-valued fields

Tags: database, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010, multivalue

In my MS Access application, I have a requirement to extract a field (which is multi-valued) and show its contents in a textbox on a form.

I have identified that for multi-valued fields there are two things: tableName.[FieldName] (field with multi-valued property ) and tableName.[fieldName].Value (single-valued field).

My doubts are:

1. Why the same field has two different representations?
2. Why cant we use JOIN clause on multi-valued fields?
3. Is there a way to use JOIN clause on multi-valued fields?

Comment: Are you using Sharepoint? If not, there is no need for multi-value fields. They are an anti-feature outside of Sharepoint, IMHO.

Comment: If you really must, read about them here : http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx

Comment: Thanks Remou for sharing these. Helpful. But before I finally decide to move away from my design that involves multi-valued fields, I would really like to take a final chance of understanding what they are and can I live with that. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not using Sharepoint. What I am using is standalone MS Access 2010.